# How to separate layer styles on to their own layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I know how to do this for all of the layer styles of a particular layer - I simply hover over any of them, right-click and click "Create Layers" from the contextual menu.

Does anybody know how/if it's possible to simply do this for one of a layer's layer styles rather than all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. It's all or nothing

However, nothing is stopping you from...

- Duplicating the layer
- Expanding the layer styles
- Deleting the style layers you don't want
- Keeping the style layers you do want
- Turn off the particular live style aspect on the original layer.